# custom field widget - how to add dashes to children, like core

Tags: 8, entities

In Drupal 8, I have a custom compound field module, containing a select type field. It gets values from a taxonomy. I'm trying to figure out how to hook/use the same 'add a dash per depth level' function that core uses on hierarchies in a select field.

I'm snooping around code, but not finding where/how. I hoped I could find it in  the form.inc file, but maybe I just don't know what to look for or how to use it.

EDIT: For reference, here's a pic of what I mean:
[image: dropdown image]

If it matters, here's what I've got for for this field, within the module widget:

```
$plant_parts = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('plant_part');
$parts = array();
foreach ($plant_parts as $plant_part) {
    $parts[$plant_part->tid] = $plant_part->name;
}

$element['plant_part_described'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#empty_option' => 'Select...', 
    '#options' => $parts,        
    '#title' => t('Plant Part'),
    '#size' => 1,
    '#prefix' => '<table class=\"descriptor_field\"><tr><td>',
    '#suffix' => '</td>',        
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->plant_part_described) ? $items[$delta]->plant_part_described : NULL,
);
```

Comment: Actually, I did find the core file doing this: MenuParentFormSelector.php ...just not sure yet how to apply it to a custom select field.

Comment: [This](https://www.webomelette.com/loading-taxonomy-terms-tree-drupal-8) may be a good start. I think there's a views filter that does something like this too.